# Can I submit tasks from pyspark on a windows driver machine to a cluster running on linux?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Here is the machine setup (with hostnames):

- A windows workstation (My dev box) running the driver application
  using the pyspark interface (BRL-VM212)
- A RHEL7 master node
  (brlhltcbap01)
- One RHEL 7 worker node (BRLHLHTCS01)

All have the same versions of java, scala, python, spark. The RHEL7 machines use java, scala, python, spark installs that are separate to the distro provided ones, and installed at a network share location so their setup is identical. Its the windows driver machine that is different.

I'm using spark in standalone mode.

However, the location of the python virtual env on the driver machine and the master/worker nodes is different (as you might expect).

When I try to run a simple sum over a list, I get this error.

```
16/04/08 11:07:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local): java.io.IOExcept
ion: Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Suffice to say, this file exists on the driver machine, but not on the worker.

Full trace

```
PS C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin> .\pyspark
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/04/08 11:06:25 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.1
16/04/08 11:06:25 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java cl
asses where applicable
16/04/08 11:06:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: john.richardson
16/04/08 11:06:25 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: john.richardson
16/04/08 11:06:25 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view perm
issions: Set(john.richardson); users with modify permissions: Set(john.richardson)
16/04/08 11:06:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 51792.
16/04/08 11:06:26 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/04/08 11:06:26 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/04/08 11:06:26 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@BRL-VM212:
51805]
16/04/08 11:06:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 51805.
16/04/08 11:06:26 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/04/08 11:06:26 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/04/08 11:06:26 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\john.richardson\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr
-d0931357-e33f-460d-b42f-86df3f037e8f
16/04/08 11:06:26 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.5 MB
16/04/08 11:06:26 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/04/08 11:06:26 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
16/04/08 11:06:26 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4041.
16/04/08 11:06:26 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://172.16.25.62:4041
16/04/08 11:06:27 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://brlhltcbap01.bluecrest.local:7077...
16/04/08 11:06:27 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20160408100627-0008
16/04/08 11:06:27 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20160408100627-0008/0 on worker-20160407160542-10.4
2.0.196-53910 (10.42.0.196:53910) with 6 cores
16/04/08 11:06:27 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20160408100627-0008/0 on hostPort 10.42.0.19
6:53910 with 6 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
16/04/08 11:06:27 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on
 port 51850.
16/04/08 11:06:27 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 51850
16/04/08 11:06:27 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/04/08 11:06:27 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 172.16.25.62:51850 with 511.5 MB RAM, Block
ManagerId(driver, 172.16.25.62, 51850)
16/04/08 11:06:27 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/04/08 11:06:27 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160408100627-0008/0 is now RUNNING
16/04/08 11:06:27 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached min
RegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015 01:54:25)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
>>> 16/04/08 11:06:30 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (brlhlhtcs01.bluec
rest.local:48100) with ID 0
16/04/08 11:06:30 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local:45735 with 511.
5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, 45735)

>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> distData = sc.parallelize(data)
>>> sum = distData.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: reduce at <stdin>:1
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (reduce at <stdin>:1) with 6 output partitions
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (reduce at <stdin>:1)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (PythonRDD[1] at reduce at <stdin>:1), which has no missin
g parents
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.7 KB, free 3.7 KB)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.5 KB, free 6.2
KB)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 172.16.25.62:51850 (size: 2.5 KB, free: 5
11.5 MB)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 6 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (PythonRDD[1] at reduce at <stdin>:1)

16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 6 tasks
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 0,P
ROCESS_LOCAL, 2064 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 1,P
ROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 2,P
ROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 3,P
ROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 4,P
ROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 5,P
ROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local:45735 (size:
2.5 KB, free: 511.5 MB)
16/04/08 11:07:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local): java.io.IOExcept
ion: Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 14 more

16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java.
io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direct
ory) [duplicate 1]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java.
io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direct
ory) [duplicate 2]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java.
io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direct
ory) [duplicate 3]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 3,P
ROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 0,P
ROCESS_LOCAL, 2064 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 8, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 4,P
ROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 9, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 5,P
ROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java.
io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direct
ory) [duplicate 4]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java.
io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direct
ory) [duplicate 5]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 10, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 2,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 11, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 1,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java.
io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direct
ory) [duplicate 6]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 12, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 3,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 8) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java.
io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direct
ory) [duplicate 7]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 13, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 4,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java.
io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direct
ory) [duplicate 8]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 14, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 0,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2064 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 9) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java.
io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direct
ory) [duplicate 9]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 15, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 5,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 10) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 10]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 16, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 2,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 11) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 11]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 17, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 1,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 12) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 12]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 18, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 3,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 13) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 13]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 14) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 14]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 19, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 0,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2064 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 20, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 4,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 15) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 15]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 16) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 16]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 21, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 2,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 22, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 5,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 17) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 17]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 23, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local, partition 1,
PROCESS_LOCAL, 2083 bytes)
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 18) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 18]
16/04/08 11:07:44 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 20) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 19]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 0 was cancelled
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (reduce at <stdin>:1) failed in 0.728 s
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: reduce at <stdin>:1, took 0.881124 s
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 19) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 20]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 22) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 21]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 23) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 22]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 21) on executor brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local: java
.io.IOException (Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or direc
tory) [duplicate 23]
16/04/08 11:07:44 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 797, in reduce
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 771, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 8
13, in __call__
  File "C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 308,
in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent fai
lure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 18, brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Pyth
on35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 14 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(
DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Python35_virtuals\GeneralDev\Scripts\python.exe": error=2, No suc
h file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 14 more

>>> 16/04/08 11:08:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on 172.16.25.62:51850 in memory (size: 2.5 KB, f
ree: 511.5 MB)
16/04/08 11:08:26 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on brlhlhtcs01.bluecrest.local:45735 in memory (size
: 2.5 KB, free: 511.5 MB)
16/04/08 11:08:26 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 2
```

It seems like the worker node is trying to use a python exe located at the same local path as the driver node. Is this expected? even if I put that virtual env on a share that both the worker node and driver node can see, they are still running different OS's?

I tried setting the spark.driver.host value to the driver hostname (BRL-VM212). All the machines are on the same internal network (same data centre also).

Thanks!

Comment: It involves `python` and `windows` - not the main use-case for `spark`. IMHO it is possible this will be a genuine bug. I would try to use Linux locally (for instance `VirtualBox`)

Comment: can you try with spark-submit and use the options like --master, --deploy-mode cluster. check out the link for more info https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: @avloss I don't really see why. Developers use the OS they want to create python code they want to run on the cluster. I don't see why the originating OS matters?

Comment: @kunal see answer below - it couldn't fit in the original question.

Comment: I'm not saying it shouldn't work, all I am saying is that Spark is Open Source project, with a lot of features, and there are bug, which are being fixed. If there was a bug with some very common set-up, it would be noticed and fixed quite quickly, but as your use-case seems more exotic to me, I am saying that this could be a bug - reported already or not.