# Problem submitting Pyspark jobs from Windows Driver to Ubuntu Spark Cluster

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, ubuntu, pyspark

I am having trouble submitting a Pyspark job from my Windows driver machine (Win 10) to a simple Spark cluster running on Ubuntu.
There are several posts already that attempt to answer this question, most notably this one from ThatDataGuy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495921/can-i-submit-tasks-from-pyspark-on-a-windows-driver-machine-to-a-cluster-running) but none of them have helped.

Every time I try to submit the simple `wordcount.py` example to my remote master from my Windows box, I get the following error:

*`Cannot run program 'C:\apps\Python\3.6.6\python.exe': error=2, No such file or directory`*

This is a Java `IOException` generated by the Py4J jar. 
My Spark cluster is a simple Master, 1 Worker setup in VirtualBox setup via Vagrant. All machines, (my Spark driver laptop, and 2 VMs (Master / Worker) have identical Spark 2.4.2, Python 3.6.6, and Scala 12.8. *Note that Scala programs using `spark-submit` against the remote cluster work fine, as well as anything run in local mode.* Also, the code examples work fine when run on either the Master or Worker nodes directly. It's only when I try to use my Windows laptop as a Spark driver in Pyspark, against the Ubuntu Spark cluster, that this issue arises. It always returns the error above.

It seems that Py4j is trying to use or instantiate Python from my Windows Driver's python path, which of course my Linux cluster can't see. I have already set the Pyspark Python path to a different value in the cluster nodes. I have set the both `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` in the nodes environment variables (via `.bashrc`), in spark-defaults.conf, AND in spark-env.sh files. All values point to /usr/local/bin/python3 as that's where Python 3.6.6 is installed on the Master and Worker nodes.

I've also (just as a hunch) aliased "python" to point to /usr/local/bin/python3 in the nodes and then changed my Windows python shortcut to pull up the same Python version. No luck but I was grasping at straws. ;/ Error simply changed to:

```
Cannot run program 'python': error=2, No such file or directory
```

I did see an article where the Py4J 0.10.7 library does not support Python 3.7, so this caused me to drop down to Python 3.6. Error stayed the same after that though.

The only thing I haven't done is to try to setup an additional shared / synced folder in Vagrant back to my Windows Python installation and then use /vagrant/shared/python/whatever in my remote PYSPARK settings. No idea if that would work though given I'm dealing with Windows and Linux Python flavors (all 3.6.6). Ugh. :/

Any ideas? I've got a Windows 10 machine and I like to do my Python development there. I've also got 64GB of RAM so I'd like to use it. Please don't make me switch to Scala! ;)

-- Pyspark works fine in local

```
spark-submit C:\apps\Spark\spark-2.4.2\examples\src\main\python\wordcount.py C:\Users\sitex\Desktop\p_and_p_ch1.txt
```

-- Pyspark fails when calling master with `IOException`

```
spark-submit --master spark://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:7077 C:\apps\Spark\spark-2.4.2\examples\src\main\python\wordcount.py C:\Users\sitex\Desktop\p_and_p_ch1.txt
```

UPDATE: Ok, so it looks like my workaround is to pretend that my Driver (Windows laptop) knows the Python path in Linux that the Worker needs to use. Fortunately for me, I do it as this entire setup is running on my laptop. Here is the code that gets me past the error:

`spark-submit --conf spark.pyspark.driver.python=python --conf spark.pyspark.python=/usr/local/bin/python3 --master spark://172.28.128.150:7077 C:\apps\Spark\spark-2.4.2\examples\src\main\python\wordcount.py /vagrant/shared/p_and_p_ch1.txt`

Now, I should add that this DOESN'T run wordcount.py as I quickly realized that my Cluster cannot figure out Window's paths and my attempt to use a Vagrant synced / shared folder is resulting in a File Not Found on the p_and_p_ch1.txt file. But it does get me past my dreaded error. I can figure out how to stash my files on a network share / S3 / et some other day.

This puts a lot of onus on the Spark Driver knowing exactly what Python path the Cluster needs to use. Fortunately I know these settings as the setup is entirely on my laptop, but isn't the entire point of this that I am supposed to submit Spark jobs to a cluster without the Driver (me) knowing settings like the Worker nodes' Python path? I'm wondering if this is just a Windows + Linux quirk?

Comment: Hi!  It sounds like your Windows machine doesn't know where your Python executable is installed.  Can you do a file search and let me know which directory python.exe is located in?

Comment: Thanks @jkovba for the quick reply! Python is installed at C:\apps\Python\3.6.6\python.exe and my "python" alias finds this exe and loads it just fine. Also calling local "pyspark" also loads up this version of Python and I can execute the wordcount.py successfully. My issue seems to be that the remote cluster is ALSO trying to use this path (spark-submit --master et), which is incorrect. :/

Comment: Just came across this today - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938107/unable-to-submit-spark-job-from-windows-ide-to-linux-cluster. The OP is using findspark to explicitly set the python_path during runtime. This works - I can use:

`import findspark

findspark.init(python_path=/usr/local/bin/python3)
`

when running spark-submit --master but then it obviously breaks in my local mode. Would be nice to have it detect when master is being used and then I can set it accordingly. Will keep researching.